# How to disable or remove filler in CKEditor 5?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

Im currently using ckeditor 5 and it seems that every span that I add it always add `<br data-cke-filler="true">` and `&nbsp;`. I found out that this module [engine/view/filler](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_filler.html#static-function-BR_FILLER) (**BR_FILLER**() and **NBSP_FILLER**()) cause of this unexpected behavior. Is it possible to disable this module?

**sample html:**

```html
           <p>
            <comment id="thread-1" type="start"></comment>
               <span style="color:hsl(0,0%,0%);">The</span>
            <comment id="thread-1" type="end"></comment>
            <span id="thread-2" type="start"></span>
               <span style="color:hsl(0,0%,0%);">quick</span></span>
            <span id="thread-2" type="end"></span>
            brown fox
        </p>
```

**result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
var x= "some string";

x.replace(/<br data-cke-filler="true">/g, "&nbsp;");
```

is working for me.